# How do you build a custom control in UIKIt?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

My subclass of UIView handles touch events and updates internal values as touches begin and as tracking occurs.

My view controller loads this custom view on screen. What's the best way to set up my view controller to listen for the value changes of my custom control?

Comment: Sorry, I went to sleep right after writing that answer. I've updated my answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can:

1. Implement delegate methods in your controller and call them from your view, or
2. Subclass `UIControl` instead and send `UIControlEvent`s to your controller

when the values change (or rather when the user interacts with your control).

If your view is used to get some form of input from the user, then subclassing `UIControl` is a better approach.

From the iPhone Reference Library:

> `UIControl` is the base class for controls: objects such as buttons and sliders that are used to convey user intent to the application.

So the most important distinction between `UIView` and `UIControl` is whether user intent is conveyed or not. `UIView` is meant to display information, while `UIControl` is meant to collect user input.

**UPDATE:**

If you decide to go with the delegate pattern, here's how your code might look like:

In your custom view's interface, define delegate like this:

```
@interface MyView : UIView {
    id delegate;
}
@property (assign) id delegate;
@end
```

and `@synthesize` it in the implementation.

In your view controller, set the controller to be the delegate:

```
MyView myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
[myView setDelegate:self];
```

Then, whenever the user interacts with the view (for example in `touchesBegan`), possibly changing the values, do this in the view:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Possibly change the values
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(valuesChanged)]) {
        [delegate valuesChanged];
    }
}
```

You might also want to take a look at [Delegates and Data Sources](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18) in the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide.

Comment: selam, this looks like my question, could you have a look at my last 2 questions, still didn't have a good response, and I will appreciate your input. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597997/iphone-application-object-oriented-design-ideas